# why Cosine of PAD is $ \frac{r}{ DA} $ and why $PA= r$?

Tags: geometry

I was reading   about Cycloid .Link is given below

https://colalg.math.csusb.edu/~devel/IT/main/m10_parametric/src/s04_cycloid.html

My  confusion  is marked in red circle [image]

Here it is  given that $|OB|= r$ and $|CB|=t$

My  doubt is that   why   Cosine of PAD is $ \frac{r}{ DA} $ and why $PA= r$?

My thinking is that  Cosine of PAD is  $\frac{PA}{ DA}$ and $|PA| \neq |OB|$

Comment: In the linked page, in the bullet points below where it shows that diagram, it says at the end of the first one that $|OB|$ is $rt$, and at the end of the second one that $CB = DA = r\sin(t)$.

Comment: thanks u @JohnOmielan in the last  it written Hence$ |OB| = rt - rsint$ ? Im confuse again

Comment: You're welcome. As for where it states $|OB| = rt - r\sin(t)$, I believe it's a typo. It should say $|OC| = rt - r\sin(t)$ instead. This is due to it being the correct expression, plus before the bullet points it says "The $x$-coordinate of $P$ is equal to $|OC|$, the length of the line segment $OC$. This in turn is equal to $|OB| − |CB|$. We will express both $|OB|$ and $|CB|$ in terms of $r$ and $t$." The main purpose of those bullet points was to determine $|OB|$ and $|CB|$ so can then determine $|OC|$ and, thus, the $x$-coordinate of $P$.

Comment: You're welcome. As mentioned in [mephistolotl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/92046/mephistolotl)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3674066/602049), there's another typo where it says in the article that "the cosine of angle $PAD$ is also $r/DA$". You also asked about this. It should, of course, be the reciprocal, i.e., $\frac{DA}{r}$, instead. I haven't read the rest of the article, but I would now not be surprised if there are more typos, so I suggest you beware & watching for that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $PD$ is perpendicular to the horizontal axis and $AD$ is parallel to it.

Notice that the right angle of $\triangle PAD$ is at $D$, so $PA$ is the hypontenuse. $DA$ is adjacent to $\angle PAD$ so $\cos(\angle PAD) = \frac{DA}{PA}$. You have the ratio reversed.

I assume $A$ is the centre of the circle. Then since $P$ is on the circle, $PA$ is a radius and $\lvert PA\rvert = r$.

Your comment says that $\lvert OB\rvert = rt$, so $\lvert OB\rvert \neq \lvert PA \rvert$.